# Having trouble writing files using fprintf in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, file-io, printf

The data I'm trying to write is in the format:

```
write = 

    [1x100 char]
    [1x116 char]
    'n'         
    [1x114 char]
    'n'         
    [1x114 char]
    'n'         
    [1x115 char]
    'n'         
    [1x116 char]
    'n'
```

Using:

```
fid = fopen('C:/file.txt');

for i = 1:length(write);
    fprintf(fid,'%s\r\n',write{i,1});
end

fclose(fid);
```

I can't work out quite what I'm doing wrong, any help?

Comment: What does "wrong" mean?

Comment: Not correctly..?  It didn't work, though as @YisasL has answered, it was a pretty simple fix.

Comment: "Not correctly" is a very broad statement. It could be writing the wrong thing, writing garbage, writing nothing at all, etc. Be specific with your problem statements, what the expected behavior is vs. the actual result. Otherwise all we can do is guess at a solution. For example, YisasL's solution discards any existing content in `file.txt`, what if `file.txt` already exists and you just wanted to append data? We have no idea.

Comment: "What does "wrong" mean?" is also pretty broad, but I get your point. I'll try to ask better questions in future :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write:

`fid = fopen('C:/file.txt', 'w+');`

If the file doesn't exist and you want to write into it.

Comment: I was pretty sure it'd be something really simple, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this MATLAB snippet...

```
    myfilename = ('yourfilename.txt');
    fid = fopen(myfilename,'wt');
    if (fid < 0)
        error('could not open file "myfilename.txt"');
    end;
    for i = 1:length(write) 
         fprintf(fid,' The Stored Details are below  : %f ',write{i,1});
    end

    fprintf(fid,'\n The write values are stored.\n\n');

    fclose(fid);
```